# How to add other libraries as dependencies to my AAR project?

Tags: android

```
AllInOneProject
|
GameFolder lib(aar)
      |
      swipeawayDialog lib
      Toasty lib
```

I have allInOne project which contains my GameFolder library. Also my GameFolder library contains lots of libraries.

```
compile 'com.labo.kaji:swipeawaydialog:0.1.1'
compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'
compile 'com.github.zurche:plain-pie:v0.1.1'
compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
compile 'com.github.rubensousa:bottomsheetbuilder:1.6.0'
```

I dont want to add these libraries to my AllInOne project. Also if its possible , i dont want to download and add locally to my GameFolder library too.

Is there any way to add dependencies to AAR file ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a "[fat AAR](https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar)" one way or another. If you are distributing your library with Maven, you could also add the dependencies information to your configuration file and they would be fetched on demand when building a project with your library.